# Can localisation pack be an in app purchase?

Tags: ios, macos, localization, in-app-purchase

I have a MacOS app published in mac app store. The app is in English language and I want to sell other language localisation support as an in-app purchase. Can I create in app purchase to add more languages support like German language pack? Does this violate Apple guidelines or will there be any issues with it?

Comment: If it doesn't technically violate the letter of the guidelines ("in a single app bundle"), it certainly violates the spirit of the guidelines.  Users will not be happy to buy an app that claims to support German, and then discover that they have to pay again to actually use that feature.

Comment: @Ssswift App is free but only the localisation is to be paid for.

Comment: I'm sure (if Apple somehow approves this) your users will be delighted to discover how you found a loophole that lets you price-discriminate by region.  And do you think German users can't use an English app?

Comment: @Ssswift Makes sense thank you...